# Is it necessary to override equals and hashCode methods in a class if I use the objects of class to insert in a TreeSet only?

Tags: java, treeset

Suppose I have below class definition:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return this.id - o.id;
    }
}
```

Can I use it for TreeSet without implementing hashCode and equals method?